# Last Date Attended from 2 Tables SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have searched the forum, and couldn't find an answer. So I apologize if this is out there. This seems simple in my mind, however, I can't seem to get the correct code.

I have 2 tables. `STUDENT_TERMS_VIEW` table holds `STTR_STUDENT`, `STTR_TERM` and `TERMS` table, holds the `TERM_END_DATE`. I need to find a way to select the student's last term based on `MAX(TERM_END_DATE)`, but I get `STTR_TERM` duplicate rows per student. I need to get 1 row per student and their last term attended.

EDIT: Ok so both tables are linked by `TERM`.

[View Code Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq9jf.png)

As you can see, I am getting duplicate TERMS for the same student, even though I am pulling `MAX(TERM_END_DATE)`

[image: View SQL Image]

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: what is the relation between these 2 tables ? Its impossible to help you with so less information

Comment: What is the query you used that got duplicate rows?   Add it to your question so we can help debug it.

Comment: Thanx guys for your patience. I added a code image.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT STUDENT_TERMS_VIEW.STTR_STUDENT,
        STUDENT_TERMS_VIEW.STTR_TERM,
        TERMS.TERM_END_DATE
 FROM STUDENT_TERMS_VIEW
 JOIN STUDENT_TERMS_VIEW ON TERMS.TERMS_ID = STUDENT_TERMS_VIEW.STTR_TERM
 ORDER BY TERMS.TERM_END_DATE DESC,STUDENT_TERMS_VIEW.STTR_STUDENT)
GROUP BY STUDENT_TERMS_VIEW.STTR_STUDENT
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is getting the max of the combination of (`STTR_STUDENT` and `STTR_TERM`).  If you only want to get the max term of each student, you should only `GROUP BY STUDENT_TERMS_VIEW.STTR_STUDENT`.  Try the query below.

```
SELECT stv.STTR_STUDENT, MAX(t.TERM_END_DATE)
FROM STUDENT_TERMS_VIEW stv
JOIN TERMS t ON t.TERMS_ID = stv.STTR_TERM
GROUP BY stv.STTR_STUDENT
```

If you also need to get the term, join it back to `STUDENT_TERMS_VIEW` and `TERMS`.

```
SELECT s.STTR_STUDENT, s.STTR_TERM, t.TERM_END_DATE
FROM (
    SELECT stv.STTR_STUDENT, MAX(t.TERM_END_DATE) AS 'MaxDate'
    FROM STUDENT_TERMS_VIEW stv
    JOIN TERMS t ON t.TERMS_ID = stv.STTR_TERM
    GROUP BY stv.STTR_STUDENT
) a
JOIN STUDENT_TERMS_VIEW s ON s.STTR_STUDENT = a.STTR_STUDENT
JOIN TERMS t ON t.TERMS_ID = s.STTR_TERM AND t.TERM_END_DATE = a.TERM_END_DATE
```